# Credit calculator in Python - how to show result in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

Im stuck with showing the results of "Amount of interest for repayment" and "Final Debt Amount" in GUI. "Show" button should draw the result on place marked on picture. Thanks in advance!

[image: GUI example]

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title("Credit calculator")

Label(master, text="Principal:").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Interest rate p(%):").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Repayment period in years:").grid(row=2)

Label(master, text="Amount of interest for repayment:").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Final Debt Amount:").grid(row=4)

e1 = Entry(master)
C0=e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

e2 = Entry(master)
p=e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

e3 = Entry(master)
n=e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

#Amount of interest for repayment:
# K=(C0*p*n)/100

#Final Debt Amount:
# Cn=C0*(1+(p*n)/100)


Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=master.quit).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: `Canvas` can be used for drawing.

Comment: To be more precise...i need to show the results of "K" and "Cn" by pressing the "Show" button. Result should be visible on place marked on picture.

Comment: Why not just show it as labels?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title("Credit calculator")

Label(master, text="Principal:").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Interest rate p(%):").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Repayment period in years:").grid(row=2)

Label(master, text="Amount of interest for repayment:").grid(row=3)
Label(master, text="Final Debt Amount:").grid(row=4)

e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

e2 = Entry(master)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

e3 = Entry(master)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

K = Entry(master, state=DISABLED)
K.grid(row=3, column=1)
Cn = Entry(master, state=DISABLED)
Cn.grid(row=4, column=1)

def calc(K, Cn):
    # get the user input as floats
    C0 = float(e1.get())
    p = float(e2.get())
    n = float(e3.get())
    # < put your input validation here >

    #Amount of interest for repayment:
    K.configure(state=NORMAL) # make the field editable
    K.delete(0, 'end') # remove old content
    K.insert(0, str((C0 * p * n) / 100)) # write new content
    K.configure(state=DISABLED) # make the field read only

    #Final Debt Amount:
    Cn.configure(state=NORMAL) # make the field editable
    Cn.delete(0, 'end') # remove old content
    Cn.insert(0, str(C0 * (1 + (p * n) / 100))) # write new content
    Cn.configure(state=DISABLED) # make the field read only


Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=E, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=lambda: calc(K, Cn)).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Tested on ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.5.2 with results:

[image: Credit Calculator]

Keep in mind that I don't know a whole lot about economics so I don't know if my testing inputs are good. Still it shouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I will analyze this and maybe try to update with new features.